# How can i pass multiple variables from one component to the service in angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular9

How can i pass multiple variables from one component  to the service and get it in another component in angular 9 ?
**I tried so hard to solve this problem but I couldn't find any solution.**
I am trying to pass/send variable that contains some data from sendComponent to service and get that same data to another receiveComponent. After clicking button on send.Html and also navigate to receiveComponent.

**sent.Html:**  *I want to push data after pressing OK button from this html*

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="onPushData()">
   <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    OK
</button>
```

**sendComponent:**  *secondTableData,totalPrice and totalPrice these are the variables that contains data that needs to pass to service.ts* **May be this is wrong approach**

```
onPushData(){                          
    let tData = this.secondTableData  // want to push secondTableData variable
    let t = this.totalPrice;          // want to push totalPrice variable
    let d = this.totalPrice           // want to push totalQuantity variable
    this.dataShareService.onPushTable(tData);
    console.log(tData);
    this.routerService.navigate(['./billprint'])
  }
```

**Service.ts:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}) 

export class DataShareService { 

  onPushTable(tData) {
  --Do something here--
  }
 }
```

**receiveComponent:**  *i want to get data in this component*

```
recDataFromService() {
  --do something here--
}
```

**receive.Html:**  *display data here*

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of recData;let i = index">
   <td>{{i+1}}</td>
   <td>{{data.itemName}}</td>
   <td>{{data.Quantity}}</td>
   <td>{{data.retailRate}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Help me to Solve this problem plz... Share your answer if u know any idea about this..**

**Sample:**  *This is the code that contain the array of data(itemName, Quantity,retailRate ....) in secondTableData*

```
  //To Copy data of First table to Second table
   secondTableData = [];
   updateSecondTable(data) {
   let foundItem = this.secondTableData.find((item) => item.itemName === 
     data.itemName);
   if (foundItem) {
    foundItem.rate = data.retailRate;
   foundItem.Quantity += 1;
   foundItem.retailRate += data.retailRate;
   this.getColumnTotal();   //  <----- To call total Price
   return;
   }
    this.secondTableData.push({
    itemName: data.itemName,
    rate:data.retailRate,
    Quantity: 1,
    retailRate: data.retailRate,
   })

   this.getColumnTotal();
  }

   // to calculate total amount
   getColumnTotal() {
   const { Quantity, Price } = this.secondTableData.reduce((acc, item) => 
     {
   acc.Quantity += item.Quantity;
   acc.Price += item.retailRate;
   return acc;
   }, {
   Quantity: 0,
   Price: 0
  });
  this.totalQuantity = Quantity;
  this.totalPrice = Price;
  }
```

**Receive.html:** *This is the code where I want to display data in array*

I want to push these variables(secondTableData, totalQuantity, TotalPrice...) in receive component and want to display it in tabular form.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>SN</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let recData of myData;let i = index">  <!--i want to display here -->
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{recData.itemName}}</td>
        <td>{{recData.Quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{recData.retailRate}}</td>
        <td></td>
        
    </tr>
    <tr class="small" style="height: 10px;">
        <td colspan="3" style="border: none;"></td>
        <td>Gross Amount:</td>
        <td>1100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="small">
        <td colspan="3" style="border: none;"></td>
        <td>Discount:</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="small">
        <td colspan="3" style="border: none;"></td>
        <td>VAT</td>
        <td>30</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="small">
        <td colspan="3" style="border: none;"></td>
        <td>Net Amont</td>
        <td>1030</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a transfer object containing everything you want (if you wish to send all of the variables using a single call):

```js
const tData = this.secondTableData; variable
const t = this.totalPrice;
const d = this.totalQuantity;

const obj = {tData, t, d};
    
this.dataShareService.onPushTable(obj);
```

Then on your service:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) 
export class DataShareService {
  private yourData;

  onPushTable(obj) {
    this.yourData = obj;
  }

  getYourData() {
    return this.yourData;
  }
}
```

And in your component:

```js
recDataFromService() {
  this.myData = this.dataShareService.getYourData();
}
```

**[UPDATE PER COMMENTS]**

The above answer isn't wrong at all => without further information, I think you're just trying to get the data at the wrong place/moment. To avoid this problem, you should adopt a reactive approach in the service:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) 
export class DataShareService {
  private _yourData$: BehaviorSubject<{tData:any[];t:number;d:number}> =
      new BehaviorSubject<{tData:any[];t:number;d:number}>({tData:[],t:0,d:0});

  onPushTable(obj) {
    this._yourData$.next(obj ? obj : {tData:[],t:0,d:0});
    // if you're using ts >= 3.9.x you can use:
    // this._yourData$.next(obj??{tData:[],t:0,d:0});
  }

  getYourData$(): Observable<{tData:any[];t:number;d:number}> {
    return this._yourData$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

On the receiving component typescript file:

```js
_fromFirstComponent$: Observable<{tData:any[];t:number;d:number}> = 
    this._dataService.getYourData$();

constructor(private _dataService: DataShareService){}
```

And, in your receiving template:

```html
...
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let recData of (_fromFirstComponent$ | async)?.tData;let i = index">  <!--i want to display here -->
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <td>{{recData.itemName}}</td>
        <td>{{recData.Quantity}}</td>
...
```

Comment: got error:Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. This error is shown when I use myData in show.Html.

Comment: This is related to your particular type of object, which I didn't handle in my answer. You must provide more info to get a more complete answer. Basically the error is telling you you're passing something not-iterable to `ngFor`.

Comment: Then how can i use myData in ngFor? Variable secondTableData contains itemName, Price,totalprice and many more..  Do u have any answer?

Comment: Is it an array? Put a sample of the data in your question.

Comment: I have updated my code above(Sample). And I have no idea to solve it.. i am stucked here... If you have any idea then please help me..

Comment: Take a look and let me know if it's working. If it doesn't, please, put a `console.log` in  `onPushTable(obj)` to show what's being passed through the `obj` parameter.

Comment: *ngFor="let recData of myDataValue.tData;  I just used this loop and its working fine.. I have just added t.Data to display array data in table..

Comment: Thank you a lot for your effort.. Helpful Man :-) Let me ask one question.. How to I print bill after button click ( I don't need a preview of bill).

Comment: If you don't need any special format, you can call `window.print()` and it will print whatever the page visually looks like. Usually, this is not a good idea as it prints buttons, menus, etc. You should hide the undesired elements using media queries, for example. A good start point is [this blog post](https://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries/)

Answer (score 1):

Any variable stored in your service will be visible in other component if you inject its service on it.

In your case, on `onPushData`, store everything you want in your service. I don't know exactly what you want, but will be something like:

```
onPushData(){                          
  let tData = this.secondTableData;
  let t = this.totalPrice;          
  let d = this.totalPrice;           
  this.dataShareService.onPushTable(tData, t, d);
  this.routerService.navigate(['./billprint'])
}
```

Be sure your service recieves all three variables and store it on it (for example, create those variables tdata, t and d on your service and get it on `onPushTable`.

So, inject your service on the second component constructor:

```
constructor(private myService:MyService)
```

Then, it will be available on:

```
console.log(this.myService.tData);
console.log(this.myService.t);
console.log(this.myService.d);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}) 

export class DataShareService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  onPushTable(data) {
    this.subject.next(data);
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

In your `sendComponent`:

```
this.dataShareService.onPushTable({tData, t, d});
```

In your `receiveComponent`:

```
this.service.getData().subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

Then use the `data` field in your HTML template like:

```
<div>{{data.t}}</div>
<div>{{data.d}}</div>
<tr *ngFor="let rec of data.tData;let i = index">
   <td>{{i+1}}</td>
   <td>{{rec.itemName}}</td>
   <td>{{rec.Quantity}}</td>
   <td>{{rec.retailRate}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not working for me..